# Using Fields to Number Theorems in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

Being as stubborn as I am, I use Microsoft Word 2010 to write a long, technical (mathematical) document.

I want to number my theorems, and I also want to make them referenceable later on. I tried

[image: Field codes]

but this doesn't entirely work. Quite unexpectedly, the second theorem becomes theorem 3:

[image: Field results]

What is wrong with my fields?

Answer (score 1):

A possible workaround is to use a field = (formula) to calculate the correct sequence:

{ set gauss "Theorem { =(1+{seq theorem \n })/2 }" ! }{ref gauss ! }
Text

{ set stokes "Theorem { =(1+{seq theorem \n })/2 }" ! }{ref stokes ! }
Text

This produces the desired result (on my machine, at least).

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as though inserting the SEQ field inside the SET field is making n increment twice instead of just once.

I got it to work using the following:

> Theorem **{SEQ theorem \n}**
>
> This is the first theorem.
>
> Theorem **{SEQ theorem \n}**
>
> This is the second theorem.
>
> According to **{REF gauss \H!}** and **{REF stokes\H!}**,

and then adding the gauss and stokes bookmarks manually (using Insert | Bookmark).

When I toggle the field codes back off, it displays:

> Theorem 1
>
> This is the first theorem.
>
> Theorem 2
>
> This is the second theorem.
>
> According to Theorem 1 and Theorem 2,

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, this is the method I use [myself](http://english.rejbrand.se/rejbrand/msword.asp). When I wrote the Q a few years ago I was hoping for a method that does not involve 'invisible' things like GUI-created bookmarks. But they do work just fine. You can also display bookmarks in the text: see the last item in http://english.rejbrand.se/rejbrand/msword.asp#fields-bookmarks